# Why does RavenDB return a wrong total result count?

Tags: ravendb

As shown in the following unit test I expect **stats.TotalResults** to be 2 but is 3. Why is that?

```
    [Test]
    public void RavenQueryStatisticsTotalResultsTest1()
    {
        using (var db = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            db.Store(new Club { Name = "Foo1", Type = "Amateur" }); // --> Matches all conditions
            db.Store(new Club { Name = "Foo2", Type = "Professional" });
            db.Store(new Club { Name = "Foo3", Type = "Amateur" }); // --> Matches all conditions
            db.Store(new Club { Name = "Boo1", Type = "Amateur" });
            db.Store(new Club { Name = "Boo2", Type = "Professional" });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        WaitForIndexing(_documentStore);

        using (var db = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            RavenQueryStatistics stats;
            var query = db.Query<Club>()
                    .Statistics(out stats)
                    .Where(club => club.Type == "Amateur")
                    .Intersect()
                    .Search(club => club.Name, "Foo*", escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowPostfixWildcard); 

            var clubs = query.ToList();

            Assert.AreEqual(2, clubs.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, stats.TotalResults); // I expect 2 but was 3! Why is that?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `Intersect` when using multiple where clauses. To combine `Where` and `Search`, you have to pass `SearchOptions.And` to `Search`:

```cs
using (var db = _documentStore.OpenSession()) {
    RavenQueryStatistics stats;
    var query = db.Query<Club>()
        .Customize(_ => _.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
            .Statistics(out stats)
            .Where(club => club.Type == "Amateur")
            .Search(
                club => club.Name,
                "Foo*", 
                escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowPostfixWildcard, 
                options:SearchOptions.And);

    var clubs = query.ToList();

    Assert.AreEqual(2, clubs.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, stats.TotalResults); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas! Thanks for your answer. Does that mean that the Intersect clause can only be used with Where clauses or are there any others clauses where it can also be used? Raven's documentation is quite thin about this topic http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-use-intersect